# Save_post - Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: functions, customization, filters, hooks, actions

I'm trying to populate an ACF field on save (updating or creating the post) while running a geolocate function using mapbox. I'm getting a cannot modify header information error when hitting the update button.

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\****\public\wp-content\themes\***\mapbox\GeocodeResponse.php:22) in C:\****\public\wp-admin\post.php on line 223`

My two files are brought in like this:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/mapbox/Mapbox.php';
require_once get_template_directory() . '/mapbox/custom-geocode.php';
```

Code in my custom-geocode.php:

```
function geolocate_test( $post_id ) {
    $mapbox         = new Mapbox("mykey");
    $field_group    = get_field('address');
    $address        = $field_group['line_1'] . ' ' . $field_group['line_2'] . ' ' . $field_group['city'] . ', ' . $field_group['state'] . ' ' . $field_group['zip'] . ' ' . $field_group['country'];

    $res    = $mapbox->geocode($address);
    $long   = $res[0]['center'][0];
    $lat    = $res[0]['center'][1];
    $value  = [
        'latitude' => $lat,
        'longitude' => $long
     ];

    update_field('address', $value, $post_id );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'geolocate_test' );
```

I'm using this same exact code elsewhere when updating taxonomies using, **create_taxonomy &  edit_taxonomy**, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when saving/updating a post.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your page is trying to redirect but failing, because the headers are already sent - which likely means either an error is being output (maybe check your error logs) or possibly you just have white space before an opening PHP tag.

Comment: What is on line 22 in `wp-content\themes\***\mapbox\GeocodeResponse.php`

Comment: @Cyclonecode ```$this->resultCount = count($this->body['features']);```

Comment: That entire file can be seen here: https://github.com/mapbox/geocoding-example/blob/master/php/GeocodeResponse.php

Comment: Well this works fine for me so I guess you must have some error output, try enabling debug in your `wp-config.php` e.g `define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_ERROR_LOG', true);` and see if you get any error messages in `wp-conten/debug.log`.

Comment: Can you also check what `$field_group` actually contains?

Comment: So with debug on I get a ``Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in`` warning for line 22. Still getting all of the modify header warnings below it. I'm also able to add ```array()``` around ```$this->body['features']``` and the warning goes away but I'm not getting a response from the API.

So strange because like I said this exact code is being used for edit_taxonomy, create_taxonomy. The only issue is with save_post.

Comment: ```$field_group``` is just an address, which is a string.

Comment: Well it turns out that the issue must be related to my local environment because when I tried it on our dev site everything worked fine. Not really sure why but I guess this is solved.